# Facebook SDK for IOS in FLutter

Tags: ios, swift, facebook, flutter

I'm trying to add the Facebook SDK in my flutter project but i don't know the proper Swift code to put in the `AppDelegate.swift`. Following this [guide](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/getting-started/) I should paste this code:

```
//  AppDelegate.swift

import UIKit
import FBSDKCoreKit

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    func application(
        _ application: UIApplication,
        didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?
    ) -> Bool {

        ApplicationDelegate.shared.application(
            application,
            didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions
        )

        return true
    }

    func application(
        _ app: UIApplication,
        open url: URL,
        options: [UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]
    ) -> Bool {

        ApplicationDelegate.shared.application(
            app,
            open: url,
            sourceApplication: options[UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey.sourceApplication] as? String,
            annotation: options[UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey.annotation]
        )

    }  

}
```

But the Flutter project has a different default code than the native:

```
import UIKit
import Flutter

@UIApplicationMain
@objc class AppDelegate: FlutterAppDelegate {
  override func application(
    _ application: UIApplication,
    didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?
  ) -> Bool {
    GeneratedPluginRegistrant.register(with: self)
    return super.application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
  }
}
```

Does anybody knows the proper way to merge them together?

Comment: just add new function i.e. second function as usual with extra suggestions from xcode if any error occurs. Seems like you don't need to change first function as it is same with minor changes by flutter. Might have to add another function to "SceneDelegate" as docs suggest.

Comment: Well, in the end the guide from facebook didn't work, i installed the FacebookCore through the podfile and left this file without a change.

Comment: not surprised as there is always some changes in flutter and facebook didn't update docs.

Comment: Is anyone with the Solution yet? I'm stuck with this.

Comment: @GuilhermeZamberlamPomini why you guys are writing native code for IOS? 
I use facebook sdk in my flutter app for facebook events. I did not have to write any client side code

Comment: @GuilhermeZamberlamPomini let me know why you are using fb sdk? Like is it for facebook_app_events or other services. I can help you with it hopefully

Comment: @KamrulHasanJony this is my own case facebook_app_events

Comment: @GuilhermeZamberlamPomini are you using this package: https://pub.dev/packages/facebook_app_events. ???

Comment: You can use the normal flutter appdelegate.swift codes and it should work.. for reference please check https://github.com/oddbit/flutter_facebook_app_events/blob/develop/example/ios/Runner/AppDelegate.swift